# Adding a constraint to a function

Tags: r, optimization, constraints

I have a function that is meant for optimizing a portfolio. I need to add a constraint to a part of it, and not the parameters

```
pps = function(x, wb, nt, ret, m12, mktcap, btm, rr){
  wi = wb + nt * (x[1]*m12 + x[2]*mktcap + x[3]*btm)
  wret = rowSums(wi*ret,na.rm=TRUE)
  ut = ((1 + wret)^(1 - rr))/(1 - rr)
  u = -mean(ut)
  return(u)
}
```

The function is ran through optim to solve for the parameters. What I want to do is to add a constraint to `wi` so that the sum of `wi` for each iteration is 0. All the solutions I have found here constrain the parameters, and I was not able to apply any of them to my code.

```
res_save = matrix(NA, 330, 3)
weights = matrix(NA, 330, ncol(ret))
for(i in 1:330){
  opt = optim(c(0, 0, 0), pps, wb = wb, nt = nt, ret = ret[1:(48 + i), ],
          m12 = m12[1:(48 + i), ], mktcap = mktcap[1:(48 + i), ],
          btm = btm[1:(48 + i), ],
          rr = rr, method = "BFGS")
  res = opt$par
  w = wb + nt*(res[1]*m12[i + 49, ] + res[2]*mktcap[i + 49, ] + res[3]*btm[i + 49, ])
  weights[i, ] = w
  res_save[i, ] = res
}
```

Is there anyone who can help me out with this?

Thanks a lot! 
(ps the code is not mine, it is from insightR)